# Sort repeating data block with header and tail using awk and sed

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I have files consist of multiple repeating datablock, such as:

```
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
 5846 4 1 1579 0         0.943         0.944         2.004        -0.477
 6276 4 2 859 775 0         0.936         0.948         1.892         2.000        -0.836
 6311 4 3 5075 6225 5757 0         0.637         0.622         0.400         1.663         2.000        -0.729
 6381 4 2 2815 4471 0         0.934         0.925         1.861         2.000        -0.737
 159 4 2 2275 4444 0         0.928         0.936         1.867         2.000        -0.745
 442 5 4 504 1979 3483 584 0         0.910         0.937         0.945         0.931         3.898         0.000         1.420
 504 4 2 2230 442 0         0.895         0.910         1.815         2.000        -0.769
 584 4 2 442 7135 0         0.931         0.813         1.748         2.000        -0.666
 1549 5 4 6293 1979 2256 4130 0         0.908         0.924         0.948         0.932         3.847         0.000         1.407
 6329 4 3 6999 1927 5757 0         0.129         0.917         0.531         1.579         2.000        -0.739
# tail1
# tail2
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
 6104 4 2 2815 3250 0         0.933         0.926         1.866         2.000        -0.729
 7035 3 6 45 7395 7220 5576 7135 5046 0         0.320         0.182         0.586         0.721         0.295         0.759         2.864         0.000         1.239
 7220 4 3 5892 7035 454 0         0.566         0.586         0.704         1.856         2.000        -0.724
 7395 3 6 45 576 2060 3326 7035 7263 0         0.685         0.341         0.493         0.594         0.182         0.256         2.692         0.000         1.128
 454 5 4 7220 6363 1851 3638 0         0.704         0.913         0.941         0.935         3.575         0.000         1.150
 7146 4 2 838 2830 0         0.905         0.927         1.844         2.000        -0.729
 7135 3 5 584 7035 5576 887 5046 0         0.813         0.295         0.249         0.242         0.542         2.192         0.000         1.101
 838 5 4 7146 2723 7250 2816 0         0.905         0.937         0.923         0.926         3.814         0.000         1.481
 877 5 4 111 887 1884 6108 0         0.916         0.913         0.938         0.937         3.787         0.000         1.450
 887 4 3 7135 877 5372 0         0.242         0.913         0.622         1.780         2.000        -0.722
# tail1
# tail2
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
....
```

Each data block has 4 header lines and 2 tail lines, and there are 10 data lines with varying columns between header lines and tail lines. So, each data block has 16 lines in total. Data with the same format repeats until the end of the file.

I wish to sort this data based on the first column only inside the data block, to make the example like the following:

```
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
 159 4 2 2275 4444 0         0.928         0.936         1.867         2.000        -0.745
 442 5 4 504 1979 3483 584 0         0.910         0.937         0.945         0.931         3.898         0.000         1.420
 504 4 2 2230 442 0         0.895         0.910         1.815         2.000        -0.769
 584 4 2 442 7135 0         0.931         0.813         1.748         2.000        -0.666
 1549 5 4 6293 1979 2256 4130 0         0.908         0.924         0.948         0.932         3.847         0.000         1.407
 5846 4 1 1579 0         0.943         0.944         2.004        -0.477
 6276 4 2 859 775 0         0.936         0.948         1.892         2.000        -0.836
 6311 4 3 5075 6225 5757 0         0.637         0.622         0.400         1.663         2.000        -0.729
 6329 4 3 6999 1927 5757 0         0.129         0.917         0.531         1.579         2.000        -0.739
 6381 4 2 2815 4471 0         0.934         0.925         1.861         2.000        -0.737
# tail1
# tail2
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
 454 5 4 7220 6363 1851 3638 0         0.704         0.913         0.941         0.935         3.575         0.000         1.150
 838 5 4 7146 2723 7250 2816 0         0.905         0.937         0.923         0.926         3.814         0.000         1.481
 877 5 4 111 887 1884 6108 0         0.916         0.913         0.938         0.937         3.787         0.000         1.450
 887 4 3 7135 877 5372 0         0.242         0.913         0.622         1.780         2.000        -0.722
 6104 4 2 2815 3250 0         0.933         0.926         1.866         2.000        -0.729
 7035 3 6 45 7395 7220 5576 7135 5046 0         0.320         0.182         0.586         0.721         0.295         0.759         2.864         0.000         1.239
 7135 3 5 584 7035 5576 887 5046 0         0.813         0.295         0.249         0.242         0.542         2.192         0.000         1.101
 7146 4 2 838 2830 0         0.905         0.927         1.844         2.000        -0.729
 7220 4 3 5892 7035 454 0         0.566         0.586         0.704         1.856         2.000        -0.724
 7395 3 6 45 576 2060 3326 7035 7263 0         0.685         0.341         0.493         0.594         0.182         0.256         2.692         0.000         1.128
# tail1
# tail2
# header1
# header2
# header3
# header4
....
```

In other words, I hope to sort every 5th line to the 14th line, leaving header and tail lines intact. For each data block:

```
Line 1~4 = header = just print
Line 5~14 = data = sort by column #1 and print 
Line 15~16 = tail = just print 
....
```

For only a single data block, I can use something like:

```
sort -gk1 data.txt > sorted_data.txt
```

But for the repeating data block with multiple header lines and tail lines, not sure what can I do. I think I need to use awk and NR to select the target data of the input file and then use sort command, but I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Based on karakfa's answer and Ed's comment:  `awk 'BEGIN{cmd="sort -gk1"} /^#[ht]/{close(cmd); print; next}{print | cmd}' data.txt`

Comment: @tink No, it does not sort out the input data per datablock. It sorted the data the entire file, but without considering the data block. So sort is performed for the entire data at once.

Comment: "awk 'BEGIN{cmd="sort -gk1"} /^#/{close(cmd); print; next}{print | cmd}' data.txt" This works but could you write an answer to explain the detail of each parts? For example, what is [ht] doing in your answer? 

Also, what if the header and tail do not use # but just random texts? In that case, I think I need to use the line number...

Comment: It worked as expected on the snippet you provided. If that's not what your actual data looks like I can't help you..

Comment: @tink Sorry, there should be a space between # and header and tail, I wrote the wrong example. So it looks like # header and # tail. I modified the post. That is the reason [ht] was not working. But can I use the line number from this awk + sort command?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{cmd="sort -gk1"} /^# [ht]/{close(cmd); print; next}{print | cmd}' data.txt` .. never mind, still a dupe.

Comment: @tink Could you at least let me know where can I understand these commands part by part, and where can I learn to modify that command to use line numbers? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `awk`, but care must be taken to build two arrays, one containing the number at the beginning of the number lines, and a second containing the entire numbered line. You keep the arrays in sort-order as the numbered records are found, and then output the stored array holding the complete lines when then first `"#tail"` line is found. All other records are just output, e.g.

```
awk '
    $1~/^[0-9]+/ {                          # rule1 - lines beginning with numbers
        for (i=1; i<=n && $1>a[i]; i++) {}  # scan forward until $1 sorts after a[i]
        for (j = n; j>=i; j--) {            # move existing elements up by 1 from i
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            b[j+1] = b[j]
        }
        a[i] = $1                           # add current record in sort order 
        b[i] = $0
        n++                                 # increment element count
        next                                # skip to next record
    }
    n && $1~/#tail/ {                       # rule2 - handle 1st #tail after numbers
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)                # loop outputting sorted lines
            print b[i]
        print $0                            # print current #tail
        n=0                                 # zero array element count
        delete a                            # delete both arrays
        delete b
        next                                # skip to next record
    }
    { print }                               # rule3 - all other records, just print
' datablock
```

**Example Output**

With your example data in the file named `datablock`, you can just select-copy and middle-mouse paste the snippet above in an xterm with the current working directory holding the `datablock` file (adjust the filename as needed)

```
awk '
>     $1~/^[0-9]+/ {                          # rule1 - lines beginning with numbers
>         for (i=1; i<=n && $1>a[i]; i++) {}  # scan forward until $1 sorts after a[i]
>         for (j = n; j>=i; j--) {            # move existing elements up by 1 from i
>             a[j+1] = a[j];
>             b[j+1] = b[j]
>         }
>         a[i] = $1                           # add current record in sort order
>         b[i] = $0
>         n++                                 # increment element count
>         next                                # skip to next record
>     }
>     n && $1~/#tail/ {                       # rule2 - handle 1st #tail after numbers
>         for (i=1; i<=n; i++)                # loop outputting sorted lines
>             print b[i]
>         print $0                            # print current #tail
>         n=0                                 # zero array element count
>         delete a                            # delete both arrays
>         delete b
>         next                                # skip to next record
>     }
>     { print }                               # rule3 - all other records, just print
> ' datablock
#header1
#header2
#header3
#header4
 159 4 2 2275 4444 0         0.928         0.936         1.867         2.000        -0.745
 442 5 4 504 1979 3483 584 0         0.910         0.937         0.945         0.931         3.898         0.000         1.420
 504 4 2 2230 442 0         0.895         0.910         1.815         2.000        -0.769
 584 4 2 442 7135 0         0.931         0.813         1.748         2.000        -0.666
 1549 5 4 6293 1979 2256 4130 0         0.908         0.924         0.948         0.932         3.847         0.000         1.407
 5846 4 1 1579 0         0.943         0.944         2.004        -0.477
 6276 4 2 859 775 0         0.936         0.948         1.892         2.000        -0.836
 6311 4 3 5075 6225 5757 0         0.637         0.622         0.400         1.663         2.000        -0.729
 6329 4 3 6999 1927 5757 0         0.129         0.917         0.531         1.579         2.000        -0.739
 6381 4 2 2815 4471 0         0.934         0.925         1.861         2.000        -0.737
#tail1
#tail2
#header1
#header2
#header3
#header4
 454 5 4 7220 6363 1851 3638 0         0.704         0.913         0.941         0.935         3.575         0.000         1.150
 838 5 4 7146 2723 7250 2816 0         0.905         0.937         0.923         0.926         3.814         0.000         1.481
 877 5 4 111 887 1884 6108 0         0.916         0.913         0.938         0.937         3.787         0.000         1.450
 887 4 3 7135 877 5372 0         0.242         0.913         0.622         1.780         2.000        -0.722
 6104 4 2 2815 3250 0         0.933         0.926         1.866         2.000        -0.729
 7035 3 6 45 7395 7220 5576 7135 5046 0         0.320         0.182         0.586         0.721         0.295         0.759         2.864         0.000         1.239
 7135 3 5 584 7035 5576 887 5046 0         0.813         0.295         0.249         0.242         0.542         2.192         0.000         1.101
 7146 4 2 838 2830 0         0.905         0.927         1.844         2.000        -0.729
 7220 4 3 5892 7035 454 0         0.566         0.586         0.704         1.856         2.000        -0.724
 7395 3 6 45 576 2060 3326 7035 7263 0         0.685         0.341         0.493         0.594         0.182         0.256         2.692         0.000         1.128
#tail1
#tail2
#header1
#header2
#header3
#header4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.